# How do you format a dictionary into a 5x5 grid?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to print my dictionary into a 5x5 grid but dont know how to do that.

```
game_dict = {(0,0): 0, (0,1): 0, (0,2): 0, (0,3): 0, (0,4): 0, 
             (1,0): 0, (1,1): 0, (1,2): 0, (1,3): 0, (1,4): 0,
             (2,0): 0, (2,1): 0, (2,2): 0, (2,3): 0, (2,4): 0,
             (3,0): 0, (3,1): 0, (3,2): 0, (3,3): 0, (3,4): 0,
             (4,0): 0, (4,1): 0, (4,2): 0, (4,3): 0, (4,4): 0}

print(*game_dict.values())
```

This prints out 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I would like it to print

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

current_position = (0, 0)

game_dict[str(current_position)] ="X"

```
X 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want quite easily, by iterating through your coordinates:

```py
width = 5
height = 5
for y in range(height):
    row = [game_dict[(x, y)] for x in range(width)]
    print(*row)
```

However, if your coordinates are always integers, you can make this even simpler by just using a list of lists.

Comment: As of 3.6, the standard dict maintains insertion order by default.

Comment: Interesting... but actually it's only in Python 3.7 that it's guaranteed as part of the spec

Comment: Correct.  It's an implementation detail of CPython in 3.6, codified in the spec in 3.7.

Comment: Ok so the code you provided worked but how would you include game_dict[str(current_position)] ="X" to that code so "X" would represent the coordinates?

Comment: @VincentOn that seems unrelated to the main question, but your only issue is probably the `str` call. If you remove that it should behave as you want